# how to commit modified file into repository

Tags: svn, unix

I have a file in my repository that has been modified. i.e it shows 'M' next to the file when I hit 'svn st'. How do I get it to show an 'A' so I can svn commit it?

I've tried `svn update "filename.c"` and it doesn't do the trick.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 'A' status means, more or less, "this is a new file that is not in the repository yet but will be added to the repository in the next commit". You're getting an 'M' status (modified locally) so you just need to `svn commit filename.c` to get your changes into the repository.

The fine manual has a full list of the status codes that `svn status` uses:

> http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html

Comment: @maxflow - If it worked, mark as answer. click on the tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: Also, you might wanna add `-m 'commit message goes here'` to describe what your change does. If you omit it svn will launch your currently defined EDITOR to have you write a message there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit it. `svn ci filename.c`. You don't have to "add" an already tracked files. You have to do update when you want to get the latest version from repo. And add when you are adding a file for the first time to the repo.